# Xamarin Forms - Custom Button fail firing command action

Tags: xamarin.forms, customization

I'm trying to make my own customize button and at same time take advantages of font-awesome for put their icons into.

It work perfect with its styles and looks fine, the problem are the Command implementation. It work using my custom button on my login page but it fail in others screens.

I tried fired them with click event handler and using gestures as Tapped but same problem, I debugging and noticed that my binding command property keeping null when fails,
but I have no idea how it works in my login page and in others fails the same implementation.

## My view xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"             
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"   
        x:Class="CrediPY.Custom.CustomButton" 
        x:Name="content"        
        xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:CrediPY.Custom" 
        x:DataType="custom:CustomButton">        
        <Frame x:Name="frameCustomButton" 
            Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonFrameStyle}">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonContainer}" >
                <Label x:Name="bntFontAwesomeIcon" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonLabelIcon}" />
                <Label x:Name="btnText" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonLabelText}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>        
</ContentView>
```

## My backing code xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace CrediPY.Custom
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomButton : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonText = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(CustomButton));

        public string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(ButtonText);
            set => SetValue(ButtonText, value);
        }
        
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandActionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CommandAction),
            typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomButton), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);


        public ICommand CommandAction
        {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandActionProperty);
            set => SetValue(CommandActionProperty, value);
        }
       
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandPropertyParam = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CommandParam),
            typeof(object), typeof(CustomButton), null);

        public object CommandParam
        {
            get => (object)GetValue(CommandPropertyParam);
            set => SetValue(CommandPropertyParam, value);
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty FontAwesomeIconBindable = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(FontAwesomeIcon), typeof(string), typeof(CustomButton));

        public string FontAwesomeIcon
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(FontAwesomeIconBindable);
            set => SetValue(FontAwesomeIconBindable, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty FontAwesomeFamilyBindable = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(FontAwesomeFamily), typeof(string), typeof(CustomButton));

        public string FontAwesomeFamily
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(FontAwesomeFamilyBindable);
            set => SetValue(FontAwesomeFamilyBindable, value);
        }

        public event EventHandler Clicked;
        public CustomButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
            {
                Command = new Command(() =>
                {                    
                    Clicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    if (CommandAction != null)
                    {
                        if (CommandAction.CanExecute(CommandParam))
                        {
                            CommandAction.Execute(CommandParam);
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
        }
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            if (frameCustomButton != null && propertyName.Equals("IsEnabled"))
            {
                frameCustomButton.IsEnabled = IsEnabled;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnParentSet()
        {
            base.OnParentSet();
            
            btnText.Text = Text;
            
            bntFontAwesomeIcon.Text = FontAwesomeIcon;
            bntFontAwesomeIcon.FontFamily = FontAwesomeFamily;
            frameCustomButton.WidthRequest = this.WidthRequest;
        }
    }
}
```

**Implemented in login**

```
 <custom:CustomButton
Text="{Static resources:Literals.login_button_signin}"
FontAwesomeIcon="{Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.SignInAlt}"
FontAwesomeFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"
CommandAction="{Binding CSignIn}" />
```

**Fail Command**

```
   <custom:CustomButton 
    Text="{Static resources:Literals.register_button_reject}"
    FontAwesomeIcon="{Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Times}"
    FontAwesomeFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"
    CommandAction="{Binding CRejectTerms}"
    WidthRequest="120" />
```

Comment: Did you check the BindingContext of the custom button in the screens that it fails?

Comment: well, I put a breakpoint and it reached to the my property `ICommand CommandAction`, but is null here  
`if (CommandAction != null)
{
     if (CommandAction.CanExecute(CommandParam))
         {
           CommandAction.Execute(CommandParam);
         }
}`

Comment: Yeah, I missed the binding or maybe I have accidentally erased it at some point. I was assumed it setup, my bad

Comment: @yensei So you resolve your problem now?

Comment: yes, it was solved. thanks